# Implementing identity server behind web api owin authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, owin, identityserver3

I have two different client apps written in javascript connecting to two different web api. I am trying to implement identity server 3.

1. Is it possible to have identity server behind my web api owin
   authentication api end point. In other words, is it possible to
   route /token endpoint from owin in web api to call /authenticate
   endpoint in identity server?
2. Is it possible to audit log to db in identity server including
   failed request along with user's ip and browser agent. Also is it
   possible to log user's ip even if i am calling from web api as my
   web api is being called by a user using browser?
3. In my case should i keep two different user base for two different
   projects or move all my users to identityserver. If i move all the
   user info to identityserver, how am i going to handle all the joins
   with other tables in different applications or should i keep a copy
   of user with minimum info such as id, email and name?

Answer (score 1):

It makes little sense to first call a web api and deal with authentication during that call.

Your client apps should first redirect the browser to IdentityServer where user would log in and be redirected back to your client app along with either access token (implicit flow) or authorization code (AuthorizationCode flow), depending on the client app having a back-end or not. Then, your client app would make requests to the webapi, passing the access token in the Authorization header.

As for different user bases, one approach might be to implement specific IUserService for each user base and either send a hint about which one to use in the acr_values or tie it to specific clients registered in IdentityService. Again, depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have identity server behind my web api owin authentication api end point. In other words, is it possible to route /token endpoint from owin in web api to call /authenticate endpoint in identity server?

Yes and no - you cannot reroute those requests, but you can host identityserver in the same application as a web api. In Startup.cs, map a folder to identityserver.
It's not a good idea to do this, first of all, which api of the two will host idsrv? What if that api goes down and takes idsrv with, then the other api does not work anymore.
-> host idsrv separately, make both apis and both javascript apps clients in idsrv, login to idsrv from the javascript apps (=SSO) and use bearer tokens for the api

> Is it possible to audit log to db in identity server including failed request along with user's ip and browser agent. Also is it possible to log user's ip even if i am calling from web api as my web api is being called by a user using browser?

Yes, this should be possible, check the logging implementation for idsrv, at the least you should be able to plug in a provider that writes to a database.

> In my case should i keep two different user base for two different projects or move all my users to identityserver. If i move all the user info to identityserver, how am i going to handle all the joins with other tables in different applications or should i keep a copy of user with minimum info such as id, email and name?

Idsrv does not need to have all the user info, just an email-address is enough, you can use that as link to the user data in your api databases if you use that as unique identifier.